# Hive get_json_object(): How to check if JSON field exists?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am using Hive and the `get_json_object()` function to query data stored as JSON. The JSON has a `coordinate` key and two fields (latitude and longitude) that look like the following:

```
   "coordinate":{  
      "center":{  
         "lat":36.123413127558536,
         "lng":-115.17381648045654
      },
      "precision":10
   }
```

I am running my Hive query to retrieve data within some geocoordinate box, like this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/user.name/sample/sample1.txt'
    SELECT * FROM mytable
    WHERE
    get_json_object(mytable.`value`, '$.coordinate.center.lat') > 36.115767
    AND get_json_object(mytable.`value`, '$.coordinate.center.lng') > -115.314051
    AND get_json_object(mytable.`value`, '$.coordinate.center.lat') < 36.285595
    AND get_json_object(mytable.`value`, '$.coordinate.center.lng') < -115.085399
    DISTRIBUTE BY rand()
    SORT by rand()
    LIMIT 10000;
```

However, the problem is that for some rows, the `coordinate` field is missing, or the `center` field is missing, or the `lat` and/or `lng` field is missing. How can I modify my Hive `SELECT` query to only get rows that have a complete valid `coordinate` entry with existing `lat` and `lng`?

Answer (score 1):

I would make a separate VIEW for the table where you do

```
WHERE get_json_object(...) IS NOT NULL
```

for each field you're interested in.

Then run the given query over that view

Alternatively, fix your input source to generate some consistent data using Avro instead, for example

Comment: Instead of making another view, I can just put multiple `get_json_object(...) IS NOT NULL` checks in the WHERE clause of my original query, right? For example, `get_json_object(mytable.value, '$.coordinate') IS NOT NULL AND get_json_object(mytable.value, '$.coordinate.center') IS NOT NULL` etc.?

Comment: You can, but that looks rather messy :)

Comment: Do you know if Hive evaluates the `WHERE` clause with boolean short-circuiting? For example, if my expression is `WHERE A AND B AND C`, and `A` is false, would Hive stop before evaluating `B` and `C`?

Comment: I honestly cannot remember. You can group parentheses, though